# Received an intent in the IntentService class

Tags: android, intentservice

I have checkboxlist where the user selectes some items then I am envloping his selecting in json format subsequently I firing the json string from the alarmManager afterwards trying to send it to the `GetLLRD` IntentService class but I am facing problem I am not receiving intent in the GetLLRD class since I am not getting  any of the outputs in the GetLLRD class.

How can I fix it?

**Code in the MainActivity:**

```
                Intent intentJson = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetLLRD.class);
                intentJson.putExtra("json_data", json);

                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 3, intentJson, 0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        5 * 1000, pintent);

                System.out.println("test intentJson output: " +intentJson);
                startService(intentJson);
```

**GetLLRD class:**

```
public class GetLLRD extends IntentService {

    public GetLLRD(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
        System.out.println("test json is " + jSONString);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
        System.out.println("Test" + jSONString);
        if(jSONString != null){

            System.out.println("Test");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to register broadcast receiver in pending intent.you may
>   doing wrong by creating pending intent with service.for get notified
>   from alarm manager we need to use broadcast receiver.

***Register AlarmManager***

```
        int REQUEST_CODE= 0;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = 13;
        int minute = 00;
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);//24 Hour format
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        /*calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, peried.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM);*/
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("json_data", json);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    5 * 1000, pendingIntent );
```

***Receiver***

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
            new ShowToast(context, action);
            if (action.length() > 1) {

                    startService(context, action);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public void startService(Context context, String action) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, GetLLRD.class);
        service1.putExtra("json_data", action);
        context.startService(service1);
    }

}
```

***Register receiver in manifest and request  for using AlarmManager permission too.***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" />
```

Comment: what is `ACTION_SC_1` in the MyReceiver class? and here `  Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);`  can I replace `MyAlarmService.class` with `GetLLRD.class`?

Comment: what is `hourSet cannot be resolved to a variable` hourSet here? sw ell minuteSet, periodset?

Comment: I am stiil getting another error as 'periodSet cannot be resolved to a variable',  'requestCode cannot be resolved to a variable' and `cal cannot be resolved`

Comment: thanks but I am still  getting for `requestCode` this error `requestCode cannot be resolved to a variable`?

Comment: also i am receiving the intent in the MyReceiver class but I am not getting anything in the GetLLRD class? please help.

Comment: You have to start GetLLRD  service from broadcast.

Comment: I am starting the GetLLRD service from the broadcast as in your code!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82602/discussion-between-anoop-m-and-light).